# Required+regular validation

Tags: asp.net

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Textboxtotalamount" 
     OnTextChanged="AmountChanged" 
     Width="90px" 
     AutoPostBack="true" 
     runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" 
     runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount" 
     SetFocusOnError="True" 
     ValidationGroup="val">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
     runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount" 
     ValidationExpression="^[-+]?[1-9]\d{0,13}(\.\d{1,3})?%?$" 
     SetFocusOnError="True">F</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

in this above code can validate correctly.......but in text box i  call "OnTextChanged"
event ....suppose if i type(characters)in textbox errormesge shown at the same time ontextchanged event also called hen error occured ....i ve to stop OnTextChanged event when regularexpression raised......
pls help

Comment: What code are you refering to?

Comment: The code that got stripped out by the HTML filters because it wasn't in a code block. Fixed now.

Comment: I just improved the formatting a bit so it got more readable.

Comment: Eeeexcellent. I was just a touch lazy, but I thought being able to read it was better than nothing.

Comment: Dominic,

I'm unclear of the question being asked.  Are you asking for help with the regular expression or with getting your textbox to require text in the proper format onSumbit?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789360.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textboxtotalamount" OnTextChanged="AmountChanged" Width="90px" AutoPostBack="true"
            CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="val" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount"
            SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="val">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount" ValidationGroup="val"
            ValidationExpression="^[-+]?[1-9]\d{0,13}(\.\d{1,3})?%?$" SetFocusOnError="True">F</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

i've added. the CausesValidation="true" and ValidationGroup="val" to the TextBox.

and ValidationGroup="val" to the RegularExpressionValidator

now the OnTextChanged will only fire when all the validators in the group "val" succeed