# regular+required validation

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textboxtotalamount" OnTextChanged="AmountChanged"
         Width="90px" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount"
         SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="val">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
         ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount"
         ValidationExpression="^[-+]?[1-9]\d{0,13}(\.\d{1,3})?%?$"
         SetFocusOnError="True">F</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

in this above code can validate correctly.......but in text box i  call "OnTextChanged"
event ....suppose if i type(characters)in textbox errormesge shown at the same time ontextchanged event also called hen error occured ....i ve to stop OnTextChanged event when regularexpression raised......
pls help

Comment: Domnic, Once you have regular expression validator and required field validator, they validate the user input via JavaScript at the client end only, now in case they are passed then only AmountChanged event will be fired at server end (in case you want Amount Changed at client end then you need to add page_ClientValidate() in Javascript).

Comment: @Beginner: I beg to differ: RegularExpressionValidator performs client-side *and* server-side validation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx

Comment: @Beginner - both RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator perform client and server side validation.

Comment: BTW, this question is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code. see if this helps you.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textboxtotalamount" OnTextChanged="AmountChanged" ValidationGroup="val"
         Width="90px" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="true">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="val"
         ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount"
         SetFocusOnError="True" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
         ControlToValidate="Textboxtotalamount" ValidationGroup="val"
         ValidationExpression="^[-+]?[1-9]\d{0,13}(\.\d{1,3})?%?$"
         SetFocusOnError="True">F</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: @Heinzi: yes. But it at client side. Still one should have "this.Validate" to be validated at server side too. good practice ;)

Comment: ya one issue if i write characters message shown when i press update button then amountchanged() event called and error occured  
how can i handle in amountchangedevent()

Comment: @Saar: So CausesValidation does not initiate server-side validation?

Comment: i removed validation group="val" in textbox event then worked partialy but when i update the error occured so in amountchaned() event how should i handle

Comment: @Heinzi: Good question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx

I am not asp.net expert, but as explained at msdn, it should be at client side. Need to investigate/study further.

Comment: @Domnic: Check following

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039465/should-i-always-call-page-isvalid-in-asp-net-webforms-c

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly: You want to execute the `AmountChanged´ code only if the validator did not report any errors, right? In that case, you should call

```
if (!this.IsValid)
    return;
```

at the start of `AmountChanged`. (You *might* need to call `this.Validate();` first, if OnTextChanged does not initiate validation by itself.)

Details can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh9ad08f(VS.100).aspx

---

Clarification: At the moment, your code looks like this:

```
void AmountChanged(...) {
    ...
}
```

You need to change it to this:

```
void AmountChanged(...) {
    if (!this.IsValid)
        return;

     ...
}
```

so that the code is not executed when some validator detects an error. In addition, you must add `CausesValidation="true"` to your TextBox as [Saar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789360/regularrequired-validation/1789473#1789473)'s example shows.

Comment: At the beginning of your `AmountChanged` method.

Comment: pls give a full furnished detail......
in page load event what should i use 

and amountchanged event what should i use

Comment: `void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }`